# React Firebase upload images for each post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

In Storage need to create a folder for each post and then display all the photos from the folder in posts

Can you suggest the best way to do this? And also when the post is deleted, it is necessary to delete the folder with the photo too

Maybe you have some examples

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [image , setImage] = useState("");
const [url , setUrl] = useState("");
const storage = getStorage();

//upload function
      const upload = ()=>{
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${posts.id}/${image.name}`);

        if(image == null) return;
        uploadBytes(storageRef, image).then(() =>{
          getDownloadURL(storageRef).then((url) => {
            setUrl(url);
          })
        })
      }


 <input name='images' type="file" className="light" onChange={(e)=>{setImage(e.target.files[0])}}/>
```

Comment: Do you have to upload the same image for all the posts?

Comment: no, each post has its own image. there can also be a different number of images

Comment: You image in state just seems to be a single string, where are other images coming from

Comment: and how would it be better to upload all the images in one folder but create a link for each picture and put it in a post?